# GetByteArrayElements was not declared in this scope

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native

I am trying to create a native method in Java using C++. However, my g++ compiler keeps telling me that my GetByteArrayElements function is not declared. I have included both jni.h and the corresponding header file to my class, I do not know what is wrong. Please help me.

I have tried changing the arguments to see if that was the problem. It was not, putting `env` in the front does not help.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<jni.h>
#include"com_package_name_ClassName.h"
#define apnd push_back
#define nperm std::next_permutation
typedef std::vector<std::string> slist;
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_package_name_ClassName_permute(JNIEnv*env,jclass cls,jbyteArray ba)
{
    bool cp=false;
    jbyte*bt=GetByteArrayElements(*ba,&cp);
    std::string str=std::string((char*)bt,env->GetArrayLength(ba));
    std::string*ps=new std::string(),tmp=str;
    slist*perms=new slist();
    perms->apnd(str);
    nperm(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
    while(tmp!=str)
    {
        perms->apnd(tmp);
        nperm(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<perms->size();*ps+=*perms[i]+(i+1==perms->size()?"":"\n"),i++);
    jbyteArray r=env->NewByteArray(ps->size());
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(r,0,ps->size(),reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ps->c_str()));
    return r;
}
```

Header File

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_package_name_ClassName */

#ifndef _Included_com_package_name_ClassName
#define _Included_com_package_name_ClassName
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_package_name_ClassName
 * Method:    permute
 * Signature: ([B)[B
 */
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_package_name_ClassName_permute
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Can you also post your header file?

Comment: Check in case if the function is not public...

Comment: @tchainzzz I have put the header file in.

Comment: @Samantha It is in a struct called JNINativeInterface_. The line is `jbyte * (JNICALL *GetByteArrayElements)
      (JNIEnv *env, jbyteArray array, jboolean *isCopy);`

Comment: Did you include, typedef const struct JNINativeInterface *JNIEnv;

Comment: @Samantha It is in jni.h. It is in a preprocessor if else statement.
`#ifdef __cplusplus typedef JNIEnv_ JNIEnv; #else typedef const struct JNINativeInterface_ *JNIEnv;#endif`

Comment: Which struct in if else is active ? JNINativeInterface_ or the other one ?

Comment: @Samantha I believe the other one, as I am certain that __cplusplus is defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195831/discussion-between-samantha-and-dsoi-ununoctium).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetByteArrayElements()` is not a standalone function, like your code is trying to use it as. It is actually a member of the `JNIEnv` object that is given to you, just like the `GetArrayLength()`, `NewByteArray()`, and `SetByteArrayRegion()` members are. Please [read the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

You are also leaking all of the memory that you allocate. There is no need to use `new` at all, let the compiler manage all of the memory for you. And you need to release the Java byte array when you are done accessing its elements.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <jni.h>
#include "com_package_name_ClassName.h"

#define apnd push_back
#define nperm std::next_permutation
typedef std::vector<std::string> slist;

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_package_name_ClassName_permute(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jbyteArray ba)
{
    jbyte *bt = env->GetByteArrayElements(ba, NULL);
    if (!bt) return NULL;
    std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bt), env->GetArrayLength(ba));
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(ba, bt, 0);
    std::string tmp = str;
    slist perms;
    do {
        perms.apnd(tmp);
        nperm(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    }
    while (tmp != str);
    std::string ps = perms[0];
    for(size_t i = 1; i < perms.size(); ++i) {
        ps += ("\n" + perms[i]);
    }
    jbyteArray r = env->NewByteArray(ps.size());
    if (r) {
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(r, 0, ps.size(), reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(ps.c_str()));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

For c: `jbyte*bt = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,ba,&cp);`

For c++:  `jbyte*bt = env->GetByteArrayElements(ba,&cp);`

Comment: It gives me an error saying it is not a pointer type. The error message is `base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEnv' {aka 'JNIEnv_'}
  jbyte*bt=(*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,*ba,&cp);`

Comment: Updated with C++ variant

Comment: Yeah it has worked now. I thought jboolean was just an alias for bool but it apparently isn't.

Comment: @SolidMercury in C++, you don't pass in the 1st `env` parameter explicitly: `jbyte *bt = env->GetByteArrayElements(ba, &cp)`